How to prompt a clicked element to open in a new tab/window
I am using python selenium, and I am trying to figure out if I can make it so that when I click an element that redirects me to another page, if I can get that redirect in another tab/window instead of in the same tab/window.
I haven't tried much of anything for this yet, I have been reading the selenium website, and it hasn't given much context in regards to this.

You can switch to new tab with this
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

To switch to first page, use 0 instead of -1.
I hope it helps.
